# Use the value of an option to edit inside text with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to change the text from an option without success, this is my code:

View

```
               <select id="plano">
                  <option selected>Chose plan...</option>
                     @foreach($foodplans as $foodplan)
                      <option value="{{$foodplan->id}}">{{$foodplan->name}}</option>
                     @endforeach
                 </select>
```

Jquery

```
success: function (plan) {

        $('#plano').val(plan.id).text(plan.name); // the problem here! 

        $('#myEditModal').modal('hide');
    },
```

After the ajax request my selector lose all options instead of change the text in the option with the indicated id.

Comment: The text for a given id changes from what it was when the list was generated?

Comment: $('#plano').text(plan.name)?

Comment: I'm thinking it's just some confusion that they think they need to update the displayed text in addition to the value, when all they have to do is change the value.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I want to give the value and edit the text of this specific id, i also tryed `$('#plano option:plan.id').text(plan.name);`

Comment: So you do, in fact, want to change the text associated with an option's value?

Comment: @Taplar exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to change the text of the select itself...not the option

Set value on select then look for the  newly selected option to change it's text

```
$('#plano').val(plan.id).find('option:selected').text(plan.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short example of finding the selected option and changing the text.

```js
var $select = $('select');

$select.val("two").find('option:selected').text("Weee");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="one" selected>A</option>
  <option value="two">B</option>
  <option value="three">C</option>
</select>
```